Show two definitions of open subfunctors are equivalent
I have come across two definitions of "open subfunctors", which I would like to show are equivalent. This amounts to solving the exercise below (marked problem).
In Eisenbud & Harris' Geometry of Schemes (VI.1.1) they define open (resp. closed) subfunctors in the category $\mathop{Fun}(\text{Rings}, \text{Sets}) = \mathop{Fun}(\text{Aff}^\text{op}, \text{Sets})$. There, a natural transformation $\alpha:F \to G$ is an open subfunctor if the base change along any $\psi:h_{\mathop{Spec} A} \to G$ is representable by an open immersion $U \to \mathop{Spec} A$ of schemes. Elsewhere (eg on the Stacks project), the same condition is used, but working in the full category of schemes (ie replace $\mathop{Spec} A$ by an arbitrary scheme $X$). That they are equivalent is suggested by E&H Exercise VI-8:

Let $X = \mathop{Spec} R$ be an affine scheme. Show that the open and closed subfunctors of $h_{\mathop{Spec}R}$ are precisely those represented by open and closed subschemes of $\mathop{Spec} R$. (The same is true, and only a little harder, for arbitrary schemes.)

As far as I can see, the part of the exercise outside the parentheses follows from applying the definition to the identity $h_{\mathop{Spec}R} \to h_{\mathop{Spec}R}$.
Problem: for the general case, suppose $\alpha:F \to h_X$ is a subfunctor in the category $\mathop{Fun}(\text{Aff}^\text{op},\text{Sets})$ such that, for any affine scheme $T$ and morphism $h_T \to h_X$, the base change $F\times_{h_X} h_T$ is representable by an open subscheme of $T$. Show that $F$ is representable by an open subscheme of $X$.
I have tried to solve this problem, this is as far as I got. Applying the definition to an affine open cover $\{U_\alpha \to X\}$, we find that the pullback $h_{U_\alpha} \times_{h_X} F$ is representable by an open subscheme $V_\alpha \to U_\alpha$, and because the Yoneda embedding preserves limits these $V_\alpha$ should glue to a subscheme $V$ of $X$. Now we need to show $V$ represents $F$.
Given $f:T \to X$, set $T_\alpha = f^{-1}U_\alpha$. Then $f$ factors through $V$, iff $f|_{T_\alpha}$ factors through $V_\alpha$, iff $f|_{T_\alpha} \in F(U_\alpha)$.
If $F$ is a sheaf for the Zariski topology (as defined here), then the values of $F$ are determined by the restrictions to $U_\alpha \subset X$. Of course, this is true if $F$ is representable, but I can't see how to show this is the case.
I'm interested in making this story work to fit into the general "functor of points" formulation, where a scheme is, in a sense, the same as a sheaf on the category of affines. (Correct me if I have this wrong!) I'm also interested in the closed version of the above story, which I expect should have a similar solution.
Thank you!
Edit: as Zhen pointed out, this idea doesn't actually put the idea of "open subscheme" purely inside the functor of points formulation, as it relies on the notion of a non-affine open subscheme. Bringing these two definitions together would still be useful to me, though.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What exactly is your question?

This is the scheme-theoretic analogue of the fact that a subspace $X'$ of a topological space $X$ is open (resp. closed) in $X$ if and only if for every open cover $\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha = X$ we have $U_\alpha \cap X'$ open in $U_\alpha$. And the same replacing "for every open cover ..." with "there is an open cover ... such that". Of course it is necessary to assume the target is a sheaf for such gluing arguments to work. But the definitions you mention are unsatisfactory as definitions fora pure functor of points formulation since they presume a prior notion of non-affine open subscheme.

Thank you both for your comments! I have highlighted more precisely where I got stuck & I would appreciate any help. @ZhenLin I see your point about the "pure" functor of points approach, though I'm still interested in solving the exercise.
